# React native animation laggy when using interpolate

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, animation

I'm building an app where if I click on a button then a `ScrollView` slides in from the bottom. I achieved this by using react native's built in `Animated.ScrollView` and interpolation.
Here is an example:

```
const popUpScrollViewValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

export const slideIn = (val, duration) => {
  Animated.timing(val, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: duration || 300,
    useNativeDriver: false,
  }).start();
};

export const slideOut = (val, duration) => {
  Animated.timing(val, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: duration || 300,
    useNativeDriver: false,
  }).start();
};

 <Animated.ScrollView
            style={[
              styles.popUpScrollView,
                /*bottom: popUpScrollViewValue.interpolate({
                  inputRange: [0, 1],
                  outputRange: expanded ? [-350, 0] : [-250, 0],
                }),*/
                transform: [
                  {
                    translateY: popUpScrollViewValue.interpolate({
                      inputRange: [0, 1],
                      outputRange: expanded ? [250, -150] : [100, -150],
                    }),
                  },
                ],
              },
            ]}
          >
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

When I click on a button I call the `slideIn(popUpScrollViewValue)` method, and when I click on another button I call `slideOut(popUpScrollViewValue)` method, which slides down  the `ScrollView`.
So basically I'm just interpolating between two positions. In the beginning the `ScollView` is under the screen and on button click it slides in to a given position.

The question is is there a difference between using `translateY` and `bottom` styles?
The animations are a bit laggy, I tried both ways but neither one was perfect.
Or should I use `React native gesture handler`?

Comment: Why are you using `useNativeDriver: false`? It means that it's JS that runs the animation, which is obviously slow. Change it to true and try again.

Comment: I already tried that, but it is still a little laggy, maybe it is a little bit better.